# Test input\output

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, io

I have code for the user input:

```
class Z
  def self.input()
    val = $stdin.gets.chomp
    if val == "123"
      p "Ok"
    else
      p "none"
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test different data:

```
describe "Z" do
  it "should receive none"
    Object.stub!(:gets){"das"}
    Z.input
    Object.should_receive(:p).with("none")
  end
end
```

But i get an error:

```
Failure/Error: Object.should_receive(:p).with("none")
   (<Object (class)>).p("none")
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

How to test the output?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe Z do
  it "should print into stdout" do
    $stdin.stub(:gets).and_return("das")
    $stdout.should_receive(:p).with("none")
    Z.input
  end
end
```

Comment: i get error `Failure/Error: $stdout.should_receive(:p).with("none")
       (#<IO:0x9d961ac>).p("none")
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
`

Comment: I solved the problem. `Object.stub!(:gets){"das"}
      Object.should_receive(:p).with("none")
      Z.input
      `

Comment: Stubbing on object is not good idea, try STDIN and STDOUT instead of $stdin and $stdout